# Seurat scRNAseq convert from Seurat object to SCE object won't work

Tags: r, bioinformatics, seurat

I have the following Seurat object 'cl.719245a.seurat' and need to convert it to a single cell experiment (SCE) object. I run this:

```
cl.719245a.sce <- as.SingleCellExperiment(cl.719245a.seurat)
```

and I get the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod(generic = "as.SingleCellExperiment", object = x) : 
  no applicable method for 'as.SingleCellExperiment' applied to an object of class "data.frame"
```

I have Seurat package installed and called. Alternatively, I have tried the following code:

```
cl.719245a.sce <- read10xCounts(datadir)
```

from DropletUtils package and get an error also:

```
Error in read10xCounts(cl.719245a.seurat) : 
  could not find function "read10xCounts"
```

Any ideas on how to amend this to produce my desired conversion to a SCE object? Thank you

Comment: Can you validate that `cl.719245a.seurat` is what you think it is using `class(cl.719245a.seurat)`

Comment: Just ran class(cl.719245a.seurat) and returned "data.frame". Is this what it should be? Thanks

Comment: it should work. Make sure you loaded seurat and you have the latest version

Comment: @RyanT. class(cl.719245a.seurat) should return "Seurat", not "data.frame". Your object doesn't seem to be set up correctly.